# Torquebox: unable to work with SLIM

Tags: sinatra, jruby, server, slim-lang, torquebox

How do I launch a simple Sinatra app with [Torquebox](http://torquebox.org/) and slim as a html rendering engine?

**Plain html works fine**... whenever I use **slim** the server fails:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method join' for #<String:0xf94f510>
```

I am dying to get torquebox up and running!

**config.ru:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require File.expand_path '../hello.rb', __FILE__
run Sinatra::Application
```

**hello.rb:**

```
get '/' do
  File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
end

get '/kalli' do
  slim :some_file
end
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit tired.

How do I launch a simple Sinatra app with Torquebox and slim as a html rendering engine?

Comment: This looks like it might be due to [an issue with Sinatra and the latest Rack](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/b39d72d2a5b824b5f607b7825c4b076f527461a1) (it’s the same error message). Does fixing your version of rack to 1.5.2 solve it (`gem 'rack', '1.5.2'` in your `Gemfile` if you’re using Bundler, or add it before you do any `require` calls otherwise). Note if this is the problem you will see a different error, this error is in the exception handling code.

Comment: Server fails. Gives me 14:46:48,844 ERROR [org.torquebox.core.runtime] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) Error during execution: require %q(rack) and 14:46:49,142 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.2.x.slim.incremental.16 "Janus" started (with errors) in 8337ms